# set_error_handler function not calling autoload

Tags: php, autoload

I have the `set_error_handler()` function set to call a function when there is an error.

In that function I have my own implementation of the exception class:

```
function acs_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {    
    throw new acs_exception($errstr, $errno);     
}
```

This gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'acs_exception' not found

For some reason, this function does not call my autoload function which I have set up using:

```
spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
```

If I add the line:

```
__autoload('acs_exception');
```

before calling the class in the error function it all works.

My question is: Shouldn't the `__autoload()` function fire when I call the acs_exception class in the error trigger function??

Comment: As an aside, how many consecutive underscores can you have in a name before it becomes hard to tell exactly how many there are?

Comment: I had to add extra _ because the preview was getting all messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here's a related PHP bug report](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47987).

> Your error is triggered at
>   compile-time, which disables autoload
>   (and spl_autoload at the same time).
>
> Won't be fixed for PHP5.3 as it may
>   cause lots of other problems.

Comment: I corrected the problem by simply calling the autoload function directly :) Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed on PHP 5.4.21 - now the SPL autoload functions are also triggered from error handling functions! :)